# Got an unexpected keyword argument when calling function with *args

Tags: python, arguments

I have a Python framework that I'm trying to get to know. One of the classes has the following `__init__()`:

```
def __init__(self, identity, direction, type, app_name, *aspects):
```

Usually (for clarity for myself), I try to call functions using their keywords, such as:

```py
destination = RNS.Destination(
    identity=identity,
    direction=RNS.Destination.IN,
    type=RNS.Destination.SINGLE,
    app_name=APP_NAME,
    aspects='minimalsample',
    )
```

The exception I get when instantiating the class as above is `Destination.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'aspects'`.

I think this is because the `aspects` argument is not really a keyword argument but rather a list of additional positional arguments.
Ok, so it isn't really a kwarg, so I tried passing the 'minimalsample' argument as the first:

```py
destination = RNS.Destination(
    'minimalsample',
    identity=identity,
    direction=RNS.Destination.IN,
    type=RNS.Destination.SINGLE,
    app_name=APP_NAME,
)
```

But then I get

> TypeError: got multiple values for argument 'identity'

I think I see what is wrong here, but I have no idea how to call the function while retaining the clarity of using the keywords. Is there a good way?

This might have been asked before (plenty of times even), but I can't seem to find the answer with the search terms I'm using.

Comment: You cannot. That is not how Python works. In this case, you have to use positional arguments.

Comment: When mixing `*argument` and keywords, `*argument` is usually put first to solve this problem.

Comment: using a method argument named `type` is a signal of bad designed Python software

Comment: how do you expect the Python compiler to solve the ambiguity of assigning `'minimalsample'` to `identity` or `*aspects`

Comment: @rioV8 I'm sure there are many more signals of bad Python inside my own code. I'm actually learning from the code that I took this example from...

Comment: your first line does not suggest you write the framework you are using, the design of `__init__()` method is the problem

Comment: I certainly haven't written that framework (or any other, for that matter), and I'm not claiming I did. I just mean to say that while yes, maybe, the design of the `__init__()` isn't ideal, I won't complain since my code is much worse. I do like the Reticulum framework and the amount of effort put in the API/documentation/... Right now, I was just wondering how to call the constructor using keywords. If the answer is "you can't", then I'm fine with that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documented
[signature](https://reticulum.network/manual/reference.html#RNS.Destination)
is pretty clear.

> RNS.Destination(identity, direction, type, app_name, *aspects)

It requires you to call it like this:

```
import RNS
from RNS.Destination import IN, SINGLE

aspects: list[str] = ['minimalsample', 'largesample']

dest = RNS.Destination(identity, IN, SINGLE, APP_NAME, *aspects)
```

That approach would work just the same if `aspects` was a single-element list.

Here are equivalent ways of passing in 1 or 2 aspects:

- `... , APP_NAME, 'minimalsample')`
- `... , APP_NAME, 'minimalsample', 'largesample')`

The `*args` notation indicates we're passing in a list of zero or more arguments.
It happens that this particular library wants more than zero arguments.

The authors of this package could have chosen to accept
an `aspects: list[str]` argument,
or even `aspects: list[str] | str`,
but that's not what they implemented.
The 1st alternative forces callers to use more `[` `]` brackets
than they might prefer for a common single-aspect use case.
The 2nd alternative trades convenience against simple type-safety
arguments.

---

Sometimes you'll see a signature like this:

`def foo(a, b, c, d=None, e=0):`

You *could* call that with

```
args = [a, b, c]
kwargs = dict(d=None, e=0)

foo(*args, **kwargs)
```

Since `Destination` accepts a variable number of
aspect strings, you don't have a choice, you need
to list four positional args,
then one-or-more aspects,
followed by **zero** keyword args,
if you want the bytecode to push
all the right things onto the stack
by the time the constructor executes.

If you want to better understand the details,
[disassemble](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html)
the bytecode of some [calling](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/call.html#object-calling-api) function.

---

When a library author is designing a Public API,
there's more than one way to force callers to use positional args.

https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-does-the-slash-in-the-parameter-list-of-a-function-mean

> What does the slash(/) in the parameter list of a function mean?
>
> A slash in the argument list of a function denotes that the parameters prior to it are positional-only. Positional-only parameters are the ones without an externally usable name.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions)
refers to [PEP-570](https://peps.python.org/pep-0570),
which explains

> When designing APIs, library authors try to ensure correct and intended usage of an API

and continues with a discussion of the careful choosing of names
and several challenges.

Something you're likely to see more often in
signatures is a bare `*` star, which introduces
keyword-only args.
For example, a library author who is concerned
about (x, y) vs (y, x) confusion,
stemming from (lat, long) vs (long, lat),
might choose a signature like this:

```
def gis_location(*, x, y):
```

This prevents attempted (incorrect!) calls such as

```
lhr = gis_location(51.48, -0.46)
```

and requires a more explicit

```
lhr = gis_location(y=51.48, x=-0.46)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think I do understand what is happening (the part above the line in your answer), and I do understand how to call the class constructor. I just didn't expect there were cases where you couldn't use keywords when calling a function/...

Comment: I hadn't added links to the Reticulum package since I figured this was a general question, not specific to the package itself...

Comment: Regarding your edit: why would an author force the use of positional arguments?

Comment: @DieterVansteenwegenON4DD if you are interested in the motivations for this feature, check out [PEP 570](https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/) which proposed adding the language feature